# Is there any way to reach drop moment in Drag and Drop?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, applet

I am making a java applet that transfer files from website to my desktop with Drag and Drop.I works but,Is there any way to learn when the dropping begins?I'm using MouseListener for listining mouse acts and using my transferhandler class for transfering data.

Code below like this..

```
public class DragApplet extends JApplet
{       
    public void init()
    {       
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();

        Image image = ...;
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        label.setTransferHandler(new ImageSelection());

        MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() 
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

                    JComponent comp = (JComponent) me.getSource();
                    TransferHandler handler = comp.getTransferHandler();
                    handler.exportAsDrag(comp, me, TransferHandler.COPY);
            }
        }       
        label.addMouseListener(listener);
        contentPane.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

class ImageSelection extends TransferHandler implements Transferable 
{
    private static final DataFlavor flavors[] = { DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor };

    public ImageSelection(){ // bla bla.. }

    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        // bla bla..
        return TransferHandler.COPY;
    }     

    public Transferable createTransferable(JComponent comp) {
        // bla bla..
        return this;
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        // bla bla..      
        return flavors;
    }

    public boolean canImport(JComponent comp, DataFlavor flavor[]) {
        // bla bla..
        return true;
    }    

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor){   
        //Download starts and save "C:\\Temp\\aa.mpg" here..
        String[] ary= {"C:\\Temp\\aa.mpg\\"};           
        return Arrays.asList(ary);              
    }     

    public boolean importData(JComponent comp, Transferable t) {
        // bla bla..
        return false;
    }    

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        // bla bla..
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What feature are you ring to implement?

Comment: I implemented Transferable on my TransferHandler class.Mouse listener creates some methods like mousepressed,mousereleased..

Comment: That should have read *"What feature are you **trying** to implement?"*, but your comment totally fails to tell me.  Think of it this way.  It is a feature you are using to convince a potential end-user to choose your app. over another.  Explain the feature to me, as you would to an end user - noting that if you said to an end user what you just wrote to me, they would not have any idea what you are talking about.  So again, what is the *feature?*

Comment: My applet allows drag and drop from a website to end-user's drop target(in a folder or desktop). When the end-user presses mouse on the applet, downloading begins immediately. I want to start the downloading when the dropping begins, not the first mouse click.

Comment: OK, thanks.  It can be summed up as "won't waste any download until the drop action"?  That is good enough for me to understand the problem.   OTOH I don't quite believe your description.  Why would the JRE start downloading the resource before it is dropped somewhere? Perhaps someone more familiar with D'n'D can support your observation.  (To be honest with you, now I understand the problem, it has convinced me that I don't have enough experience to help.  I am hoping for some D'n'D gurus to pass by and take an interest in your question.)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how you create your `Transferable` since it is not included in the question. In the drag-and-drop process the `Transferable` is created as soon as you start dragging. However, there is no need to start your download in the constructor of your `Transferable`.

You can start downloading when the `Transferable#getTransferData` method is called for the specific `DataFlavor`, which is, unless the `DropTarget` is badly implemented, only called when the drop has occurred.

Comment: I have edited my question and showed my code.Please look at the code and help my problem if you are not busy.Thanks for your help.