# XPath application using tika parser

Tags: java, parsing, apache-tika

I want to clean an irregular web content - (may be html, pdf image etc) mostly html. I am using tika parser for that. But I dont know how to apply xpath as I use in html cleaner.

The code I use is,

```
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
URL u = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128696/is-there-any-way-to-reach-    drop-moment-in-drag-and-drop");
new HtmlParser().parse(u.openStream(),handler, metadata, context);
System.out.println(handler.toString());
```

But in this case I am getting no output. But for the url- google.com I am getting output.

In either case I don't know how to apply the xpath.

Any ideas please...

Tried by making my custom xpath as how body content handler uses,

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128696/is-there-any-way-to-reach-drop-moment-in-drag-and-drop");
        int status = client.executeMethod(method);
        HtmlParser parse = new HtmlParser();
        XPathParser parser = new XPathParser("xhtml", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");          
        //Matcher matcher = parser.parse("/xhtml:html/xhtml:body/descendant:node()");
       Matcher matcher = parser.parse("/html/body//h1");        
ContentHandler textHandler = new MatchingContentHandler(new WriteOutContentHandler(), matcher);
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata(); 
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        parse.parse(method.getResponseBodyAsStream(), textHandler,metadata ,context);   
        System.out.println("content: " + textHandler.toString());
```

But not getting the content in the given xpath..

Comment: Tried using XHTMLContentHandler and ToHTMLContentHandler as well. All I can get is the entire html content sans tags. Still can't find a method where I can give an input Xpath and which would return the contents present in the xpath. This is really eating lot of my time. Any help plz...

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you take a look at the source code for [BodyContentHandler](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/sax/BodyContentHandler.java), which comes with Tika. BodyContentHandler only returns the xml within the body tag, based on an xpath

In general though, you should use a [MatchingContentHandler](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/sax/xpath/MatchingContentHandler.java) to wrap your chosen ContentHandler with an XPath, which is what BodyContentHandler does internally.

Comment: Attached the logic which I used as mentioned by you.